# Prevent eclipse from trimming spaces in jsp pages

Tags: java, eclipse

When I use the shortcut(ctrl+shift+f) for auto-formatting in jsp pages it is removing the spaces from between the texts, between two buttons. I don't want eclipse to do that. For eg

```
<h1>Text not to trim</h1>
```

is being converted to

```
<h1>Textnottotrim</h1>
```

Comment: Eclipse does not do like that, there may be some other problem.

Comment: I know that it is not a normal behavior. But what could be the problem?

Comment: Take a look at Window - Properties and search html formatter. There is the way "ctrl-shift-f" works and you can edit this behaviour.

Comment: Which JSP Editor is this? Are those literally just normal space characters in between the words?

Comment: Normal spaces and spaces with jstl.